# How do I edit a WTForms FieldList to remove a value in the middle of the list

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I am trying to create a screen that looks like this:

[image]

To do this I create a form (TemplateFormRow) and then put it into a FieldList item in a parent form (TemplateForm). My form code is as follows:

```
class TemplateFormRow(FlaskForm):
    col = StringField(label='Column Name')
    data_type = SelectField(label='Data Type',
                            choices=[("boolean", "boolean"), ("datetime", "datetime"),
                                     ("integer", "integer"), ("decimal", "decimal"), ("string", "string")])
    sequence = HiddenField()
    delete = SubmitField(label='Delete')


class TemplateForm(FlaskForm):
    rows = FieldList(unbound_field=FormField(TemplateFormRow), min_entries=1)
    add_row = SubmitField(label='Add Row')
    confirm = SubmitField(label='Confirm')
```

The goal is that when someone clicks the 'Delete' button on any row, I delete that row and present the form again without it. I finally got some Python / Flask code to make this work:

```
for ndx, this_row in enumerate(form.rows):
                if this_row.data['delete']:  # This was the row on which the person hit the delete button
                    # TODO: WTForms seems to say you shouldn't do the following, but it seems to work.
                    del form.rows.entries[ndx]
                    break
```

My problem is that the WTForms [documentation for FieldList](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.2.1/fields/#wtforms.fields.FieldList) says, I think, that you're not supposed to do this...

> Do not resize the entries list directly, this will result in undefined
> behavior. See append_entry and pop_entry for ways you can manipulate
> the list.

Their recommendations of using pop doesn't work for me as that pulls the last item off the list but I may need to pull the first, or a middle, item off.

So, what I'm doing works but, is it dangerous? Is there a better / approved way to do this? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/issues/256#issuecomment-227610117 seems to be a possible solution to someone else who had the same problems as you. Removing entries not at the end of the list also seems to be behavior not implemented for `FieldList`. Since the documentation says not to remove directly from the internal list I would recommend working around that like the linked solution.

Comment: Thanks! I'll add my question to that forum and see if anyone there can confirm that this is a bad idea. If so, I'll go with the recommendation over there.